# Flutter - Show Box/Menu with List on TextField change event

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to make autocomplete for entering location data (cities)... So I have a `TextField` where users enter city name and I'm trying to make a Box below that `TextField` with suggestions from API in JSON format.

```
onChanged: (t) {
        setState(() {
          return Container(
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
                return new Text(litems[Index]);

              }));
        });
      },
```

But the problem is I don't see any box container and I get no errors in logs. What could be the reason why this box is not rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create the box in your `build()` method. And initially you can hide it using `Visibility` widget. And whenever you want to show it you can make `_visible = true`.

I'm just giving you the idea to solve your problem since you didn't share any code.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      YourTextFormField(),
      Visibility(
        visible: _visible,
        child: YourBox(),
      ),
      // other children
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know that Visibility widget exists. Thx a lot!